# Singleton использование

Tags: java

Насколько правильно использование нескольких синглтонов в одном классе? Возможно, что я что-то путаю прошу меня поправить. В этом коде реализован механизм хранения полученного и записанного в setStoreList() массива данных. С его помощью из другого активити я могу достать эти данные StoreNewsCount.StoredInstance.getStoredList(). Cейчас данные сливаются в один инстанс `StoredInstance`, вопрос в том, можно ли залить данные из другого массива в `StoredInstance2`? И правильно ли это? Спасибо!

```
public class StoreNewsCount {

    List<GetMenuItemsCount> myList = new ArrayList<GetMenuItemsCount>();

    public static StoreNewsCount StoredInstance = new StoreNewsCount();

    public static StoreNewsCount StoredInstance2 = new StoreNewsCount();

    public void setStoreList(String [][] items){
        if (myList.size() == 0) {
            for (int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                myList.add(new GetMenuItemsCount(items[i][0],(Object)items[i][1]));
            }
            Log.e("StoreNewsCount", "ArrayNewsList is going to setup");
        } else {
            Log.e("StoreNewsCount","ArrayNewsList is full");
        }
    }

    public List<GetMenuItemsCount> getStoredList(){
        return myList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Кажется, вы не совсем верно представляете, как работает синглтон. По крайней мере, ваш код им не является. Вообще, сложно понять, чего вы этим кодом хотите добиться. Добавьте в вопрос описание вашей задачи и желаемый результат.

Comment: Вообще полезно бы почитать Банду Четырёх ("Паттерны проектирования") - хорошая книга.

Comment: Спасибо! Возьму на заметку. Поправил немного описание вопроса. Сейчас понятно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала:

> Одиночка (англ. Singleton) — порождающий шаблон проектирования,
>   гарантирующий, что в однопоточном приложении будет единственный
>   экземпляр класса с глобальной точкой доступа.

Из вышесказанного: Singltone - это массивный экземпляр класса, который (как следует из названия) должен существовать один для всего приложения. В его задачи входят некие затратные с точки зрения ресурсов системы операции или, как вариант, хранение неких объектов (к примеру ConnectionPool в веб проектах). Конечно, использовать данную технологию вы можете на своё усмотрение. Вот пример:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton singleton = null;
    private String someData = null;

    private Singleton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static Singleton getSingletone() {
        return singleton = singleton == null ? new Singleton() : singleton;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.someData = data;
    }

    public String getData() throws NullPointerException {
        return someData;
    }
}
```

Как вы понимаете, один и тот же экземпляр данного класса вы сможете получить в любой точке кода, как и данные, которые обёрнуты в данный экземпляр. Пример вызова: `Singleton.getSingletone().getData();`

Дальше - ближе к телу вопроса: Если **Вы** хотите построить **Вашу** логику на хранении данных в подобном объекте и понимаете весь механизм, то проблем нет. Но ваша реализация не может называться Одиночкой. Это так, к слову. И напоследок, не забывайте о модификаторах доступа класса. Если Вы не скроете конструктор (который напомню неявно есть всегда), то в любом участке кода Вы или кто-нибудь ещё может породить новые экземпляры класса... А это чревато путаницей...